# Populating textBox with value depending on button click count

Tags: c#, winforms

I am new to coding in C#. Currently I am encountering the problem of populating a `textBox` depending on the amount of times `button1` is clicked. I have been able to populate option one but I am not sure how to get the second option after the second click and so fourth. How would I be able to do that? Also, Would I need to add a loop to start over after the fourth click?

**Code**

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     MyTextBox.Text = "Fruits"; //1st click
     MyTextBox.Text = "Vegtables"; //2nd click
     MyTextBox.Text = "Grains"; //3rd click
     MyTextBox.Text = "Poultry"; //4th click

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private List<string> messages= new List<string>(){"Fruits", "Vegetables", "Grains", "Poultry"};
private int clickCount = 0;

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   MyTextBox.Text = messages[clickCount];
   clickCount++;
   if (clickCount == messages.Count)
      clickCount = 0;

}
```